# Application crashing on calling a JNI modal dialog box

Tags: java, visual-c++, dll, java-native-interface, native

In a Java application (JRE 1.7.0_21) on Windows XP, I call a native method:

```
public native String getImage(...);
```

...which is in a Visual C++ 10.0 dll. This displays a modal dialog box. Before displaying the dialog box I am properly setting the dialog box's parent handle to be java application window on top of which this dialog box will popup.

Problem is my application crashes as soon as the call to DoModal() in this function. If I leave the handle to parent window to be null then the dialog box coming fine with no crash. Only when setting handle to parent window to java application its crashing.

Please let me know if I am missing something in dll part/jni.

Comment: Post more code, especially: how do you set up the Dialog Box object and specify the parent. How do you manage the AFX_MODULE_STATE for your DLL. Also, be more precise about "crashing". What do you see if you attach your debugger to the Java process before the crash and let it happen?

Comment: The dll is MFC Extension dll. When i add AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()) in exported function i get the 'mfcs100ud.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in myproj.obj' error. Followed solutions to this error in following post [link]http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=hi&rurl=translate.google.co.in&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http://blog.csdn.net/eulb/article/details/2580958&usg=ALkJrhiwFcu6z-sA8Ng0QNvvqHys1_tkOQ[/link] but none works.

Comment: With the debug version of the dll, on debugging going inside DoModal() call it fails the assertion at AfxGetResourceHandle() in afxwin1.inl file.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your crash?

Answer (score 0):

You normally can't use "MFC extension DLL" in a non MFC executable.

Read [Extension DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f7ck28.aspx), especially:

> The client executable must be an MFC application compiled with _AFXDLL
>   defined.

and

> Only MFC executables (either applications or regular DLLs) that are
>   built with the shared version of MFC can use an extension DLL.

Set up a new project, choosing "Regular DLL" for the MFC DLL type.

Comment: I created Regular DLL and included AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()) in the exported function. There is no build error now but the problem remains same. As soon as the the call to DoModal(), the application crashes.

Comment: Then, you must post code. How do you create your DialogBox Object? , how do you set up the parenting?, how do you call DoModal?

Comment: This time while debugging inside DoModal() it crashes in ::EnableWindow(hWndParent, FALSE); when windows tries to disable parent window which is java app window.

Comment: Crash? ::EnableWindow is an API. What's the stack frame? If the Java Framework doesn't allow that, you may be out of luck. Is the DoModal without parent a real problem for you? If yes, you may want to do the "disabling" in Java, before the JNI Call.